# Canada Express Entry Profile: Bank balance in your account

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry

I am married but don't want to bring my wife along with me to Canada. Until I have fully functional set up there e.g. a Job, a Home, Schools identified for kids, etc.

So how should I go ahead with the following information while filling up EE profile on CIC website?

They asked if I am married or not and if married how much money you want to bring to Canada to support your family. Here the ideal amount is $12k per person. So clearly a huge difference depending upon I am going alone or with family.

Please suggest what should I do.

[image]

Comment: Does it ask later on if you will actually be bringing your family? Can you try entering the amount you will have to support yourself to see what further options are given?

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to get them into Canada within eight months, I would suggest you mention your entire family AND fulfill the monetary requirements, so that even your family gets visas at the same time. It doesn't matter if they travel immediately or not, but they need to land the first time within eight months of visa grant.

If you expect that it will take longer for you to get them to Canada, it might be best to mention you are married but don't add them as applicants.

You will be able to reduce your monetary requirements if that is the case, but note that you will lose out on the opportunity to gain extra points from adding your spouse into the application in some cases.

Also note that while there is no real way to confirm this, your application decision (especially for PR) may get influenced based on your decision to bring your family or not. It's generally good to add your immediate family as applicants together in the same application.